# Pip install undetected failure modes

Tags: python, pip, installation

We have a fleet of networked machines with packages installed via `pip install`, normally `pip install -r requirements.txt`. We regularly find that a package is incorrectly installed, often in the cache directories too. Typical problems are zero length files.

I would expect that the problem here is out-of-disk, but some of the machines in question have never been low on disk.

What I do know is that we have previously had programmers who need to be educated to check the return codes of Linux utilities - maybe they didn't?

My question is this, to the knowledgeable: can I expect `pip` always to report failures such as these (and others), and will it do so via its exit code?

Supplementary question: if pip cannot be relied upon as above, is there a reasonably foolproof way to check that library modules have installed properly?

Comment: maybe these will be not avaliable with `pip list` ? You can also try to import them.

Comment: This might be better directed at the [maintainers of _pip_](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/) directly. I doubt it would really help in your case, but maybe have a look at [_pip_'s "Hash-Checking Mode"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#hash-checking-mode) as well as [_pip_'s documentation section on "Ensuring Repeatability"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#ensuring-repeatability). Otherwise I would suggest running a test suite against the installed projects to check for sanity. More generally, I believe tools such as _Nix_ or _containers_ could help.

Comment: @amh Additionally, if I understood correctly for each project installed by _pip_ there should be a [`*.dist-info/RECORD` file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/#record) containing the names of the files that should have been installed along with their hash and size in bytes.

Comment: @sinroc that sounds very interesting

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly for each project installed by pip there should be a [`*.dist-info/RECORD` file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/#record) containing the names of the files that should have been installed along with their hash and size in bytes. This info can be used to double-check that the installation went well.

I doubt it would really help in your case, but at another level (download) maybe have a look at [*pip*'s "Hash-Checking Mode"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#hash-checking-mode) as well as [*pip*'s documentation section on "Ensuring Repeatability"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#ensuring-repeatability).

Otherwise I would suggest simply running a test suite against the installed projects to check for sanity.

**Update (2020-03-05)**

[*PEP 458*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0458/) might help in the future.